# 3D bin packing algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, 3d, bin-packing

I wrote a 3D bin packing algorithm but I am still not sure if it is correct or not.

I did not follow any code or pseudo-code that's why I would like to know if it is an efficient algorithm for the 3D bin packing problem or not.

each container has a length, height and breadth

each item has a length , height and breadth.

This is the code I wrote to pack items one by one without exceeding the container's length, height or breadth:

```
private double x,y,z=0;
private double[] remainingLength;
private double[] remainingHeight;
private double[] remainingBreadth;

   //----initialize the remaining dimensions' arrays
    public void init(int n) {
        remainingLength=new double[n];
        remainingHeight=new double[n];
        remainingBreadth=new double[n];
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            remainingLength[i]=length;
            remainingHeight[i]=height;
            remainingBreadth[i]=breadth;
        }
    }

public boolean put3D(ItemsUnit item, int p,int n) {
    init(n); 

    if(x<length){
        if(putL(item,p)) {
        packedItems.add(item); // if item fits add it to the packedItems into the container
     return true;
    }
    }

        if(y<breadth) {
                if(putB(item,p)){
            packedItems.add(item); // if item fits add it to the packedItems into the container
            return true;
        }
        }
            if(z<height){
                if(putH(item,p)){
                packedItems.add(item); // if item fits add it to the packedItems into the container
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

public boolean putL(ItemsUnit item, int p) {
    //remaining dimensions arrays already initialized in the optimization algorithm
    double minRemL=remainingLength[0];
    int i=0;

    for (int j=0; j<remainingLength.length; j++){
        if ((remainingLength[j]!=0)&&(minRemL>=remainingLength[j])&&(remainingLength[j]>=item.getLength())){
                i=j; //choosing the item to which we should put the new packed item next to
                minRemL=remainingLength[j]; //minimum length left
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
        remainingLength[p]=remainingLength[i]-item.getLength();
        remainingBreadth[p]-=item.getBreadth();
        remainingHeight[p]-=item.getHeight();
        remainingLength[i]=0;
        x+=item.getLength(); //increment x
        return true;
}


public boolean putB(ItemsUnit item, int p) {
    //remaining dimensions arrays already initialized in the optimization algorithm
    double minRemB=remainingBreadth[0];
    int i=0;

    for (int j=0; j<remainingBreadth.length; j++){
        if ((remainingBreadth[j]!=0)&&(minRemB>=remainingBreadth[j])&&(remainingBreadth[j]>=item.getBreadth())){
                i=j; //choosing the item to which we should put the new packed item next to
                minRemB=remainingBreadth[j]; //minimum length left
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
        remainingBreadth[p]=remainingBreadth[i]-item.getBreadth();
        remainingHeight[p]-=item.getHeight();
        remainingLength[p]-=item.getLength();
        remainingBreadth[i]=0;
        y+=item.getBreadth(); //increment y
        return true;
}


public boolean putH(ItemsUnit item, int p) {
    //remaining dimensions arrays already initialized in the optimization algorithm
    double minRemH=remainingHeight[0];
    int i=0;

    for (int j=0; j<remainingHeight.length; j++){
        if ((remainingHeight[j]!=0)&&(minRemH>=remainingHeight[j])&&(remainingHeight[j]>=item.getHeight())){
                i=j; //choosing the item to which we should put the new packed item next to
                minRemH=remainingHeight[j]; //minimum length left
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
        remainingHeight[p]=remainingHeight[i]-item.getHeight();
        remainingBreadth[p]-=item.getBreadth();
        remainingLength[p]-=item.getLength();
        remainingHeight[i]=0;
        z+=item.getHeight(); //increment z
        return true;
}
```

I tested the algorithm and it worked fine without exceeding the dimensions of the container but I am not fully certain if the code is correct.

Can anyone read the code and tell me if it has a problem somewhere or if it is correct?

Comment: No, this is the wrong place.

Comment: this rather belongs to [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @ Kevin Esche 
oh I did not know that site exists! sorry, I will post my question there. 
And do you have another website for code reviewing (except the one you posted) ?
thank you!